# Which jar has org.apache.spark.sql.types?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.6, spark-submit

I am on Spark 1.x, and attempting to read csv files. If I need to specify some data types, as per the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema), I need to import the types defined in the package **org.apache.spark.sql.types**.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType,StructField,StringType};
```

This works fine when I use this interactively in spark-shell, but as I want to run this thru spark-submit, I wrote some Scala code to do this. But, when I attempt to compile my Scala code, it gives me an error saying it could NOT find org.apache.spark.sql.types. I looked up the jar contents of `spark-sql`, but couldn't find these types defined in there.

So, which jar has org.apache.spark.sql.types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the [source code for spark-sql](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/branch-1.6/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types) at GitHub to realize that these types can be found in the **spark-catalyst** jar. That didn't seem intuitive.

Also, since [StructType](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType.scala) has this code

```
org.json4s.JsonDSL._
```

we end up with another dependent jar - json4s-core.

Comment: if you use any standard build tool (maven / sbt / gradle) you wouldn't have to bother with this - `spark-sql` jar declares these jars as its _transitive dependencies_, which would make any build tool fetch these when `spark-sql` is used.

Comment: @TzachZohar, that helps. Thanks!